# Android Best approach when handling a lot of images

Tags: android, performance, cordova

Recently I dug into mobile development. I started with Android native, as it will probably be the first mobile OS the application will be published to, but after some struggles learning a new language, and trying to get used to new a IDE and API, I switched to PhoneGap, as it was always the plan to have the application on more than one OS. Additionally, I have years of experience with web development.

So now I come the issue I was facing, as my application will be handling a LOT of images, is how to  store all these images.
I have couple of ideas of what could be done:

1. Have some sort of cloud storage which hosts the images, and then when application is run it would download all the images to the device, but that would take a lot of storage on the device and it might take too long.
2. Cloud storage, but when application is run it downloads them into a cache to just use the ones that are currently needed and then discard them after user is done with them, maybe even try to download just one by one when needed.

The 2nd approach makes the most sense to me regarding performance and device storage, but it would force the application to always be online. In the 1st example that would not be necessary. I can't help but think there is a better way to tackle this.

Also what would be the best path here to go native, which means tighter control of the native API, but losing the functionality of being generic and have to do the same thing for different OS in each language separately or in a ways stay somehow in hybrid environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app does something similar to this, but we do it all in Java, so if you do decide to go back down that route, this could help. We have a large amount of images (more than 30,000) hosted in the cloud. The user can browse through these images (and we have pre-generated thumbnails of each) and on the client we have the following:

1. Placeholder image that is a subclass of `ImageView`, which also handles performing an asynchronous task of downloading the image.
2. Memory cache of images using Android's [LRUCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) class. The cache is initialized at startup to be about 1/8th of the available memory.
3. A DiskLRU Cache to store images on the phone's SD card. I'm currently using [Jake Wharton's DiskLRUCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache)

This does a decent job, but you'll also want to look at Google's [Managing Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) article, and figure out how you're going to recycle bitmaps if you're running on Gingerbread or earlier.

Oh and I almost forgot, you might also want to look into [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: So basically your app needs to be always online, right? And do you limit how much do you cache?

Comment: Yes, our app is about photo sharing, so it doesn't make any sense for our app not to be online. The disk cache is hard capped at 40 MB, but will be smaller if there's less space than that.

Comment: I have another question where do you host your pictures, if I may ask?

Comment: They're on Amazon's S3 service.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap/cordova apps are just native apps with most functionality in a webview, so you could leverage both the picasso code (via a native plugin) and use phonegap.

That said, I'd probably do what Carl does, but write a plugin for PhoneGap that calls into different native code for each platform.

Since you know the app is going to be cross platform, it makes sense to trial PhoneGap to see if it can perform well enough.

You could also look at doing the caching in js, leveraging some of the ideas here: https://github.com/bperin/imageCache

Comment: Altho I loved both of your answers I had to pick one so I went with Carls answer :)

Comment: No worries.  Please let us know what you ended up doing.